# Extract control out of literal

Tags: c#, asp.net, literals

I have a Literal control in my ASP.Net application, I fill this literal with a lot of FileUploads as below:

```
Literal1.Text += string.Format("<input id='File{0}' type='file' /><br/>",n++);
```

where n is a number that is not my worry, it is handled. FileUploads successfully add to page, now I want to cast (or whatever you call it) the literal text into several FileUploads (n items) and Save them all in one postback. **HOW CAN I BEHAVE THIS STRING AS FILEUPLOAD?**
I have tried this so far:

```
string[] fileUploads = Literal1.Text.Split(new string[] { "<br/>" },  
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

this gives me an array of strings each indicating a fileupload as string, **IS IT POSSIBLE TO CAST THESE STRINGS TO FILEUPLOADS AND UPLOAD THEIR FILES?**

Comment: When you add HTML via a `Literal` it does **not** create a server side control. When posting you will be able to see the value in the `Request.Forms` collection.

Comment: Use `Request.Files` To get All Posted Files.

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to do exactly but you may use RegEx to extract a string from another string using a specific pattern. You may learn more about Regular Expressions [here](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm#search). Have a great day :)

Comment: @YograjGupta Request.Files equals zero. there's nothing there when I check it server side.

Comment: Dear @Oded I checked `Request.Form["File1"]` it is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your inputs names, and on postback check `Request["inputName"]` for the values..

```
lit.Text += String.Format("<input id='File{0}' name='File{0}' type='file' /><br/>", n++);
```

On postback your file names are in `Request["File1"]`, `Request["File2"]`, etc.

PS: Maybe all you need is getting the files themselves from `Request.Files` (assuming the form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`).

Comment: Michal Klouda, Can you show me the code? I have a good background in C# but no background in html :) thanks.

Comment: It gave NullReferenceException. and Request.Files is 0.

Comment: your form needs to have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is added but still the same.